# Enumerate all symbolic links in kernel driver

Tags: windows, kernel, enumeration, symlink

How can i enumerate all symbolic links with my windows kernel driver? 
Like winobj do (GLOBAL??)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [NtOpenDirectoryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470234%28v=vs.85%29) and [NtQueryDirectoryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470238%28v=vs.85%29) functions help you.